# Calling window.scroll and window.load multiple times

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using php to output jquery as my php script executes and tells me when I need to create my jquery statements. The thing is that I end up outputting window.scroll and window.load multiple times on a single page and I don't know if that's bad practice. If it is, then what's the best way to consolidate all my jquery from the php output?

Here is an example:

php

```
if(true){echo jquery}
```

jquery output looks something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                animateScrolledIntoView($('#element1 .showcase_image'),'slideLeft');
            });
            $(window).load(function() {
                animateScrolledIntoView($('#element2 .showcase_image'),'slideLeft');
            });
```

I could potentially have many (8 or 10 #elements). Usually this could be consolidated into one .js file but since I am creating the jquery based on the server side logic, I need to know if I'm taking the right or wrong approach.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The best way I found was to create a global array which contains the element and css animation class, then output at the bottom of the page. This keeps all my jquery in one place.

Comment: echo jquery gives WHAT output?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want, but do a quick search on `"output buffering php"` on google for ways to gather all `echo()`s into one so you just send information to the browser once.

Comment: @PratikJoshi , thanks. I've added the jquery output.

Comment: Umm, excuse the question but why do you have to this for ALL elements on their own when you can just write sth like `animateIntoScrolledView($('.showcase-image'), 'slideLeft');` once?

Comment: @m90 - Thanks. Some elements will have different animations, 'slideLeft', 'slideRight' etc... The example I posted isn't the best, they both use 'slideLeft' but that could chagne. I can see why you would ask.